# Parabolic Subalgebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $R$ a root system and $\Delta$ be a simple system of roots of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, $\Delta'\subset \Delta$ and $R(\Delta')=R\cap \mathbb Z(\Delta')$. Define $$p(\Delta')=\mathfrak h \bigoplus_{\alpha \in R(\Delta')} \mathfrak g_{\alpha} \bigoplus_{\alpha \in R^+ \setminus R^+(\Delta')}\mathfrak g_{\alpha}$$ the parabolic subalgebra associated to $\Delta'$.

If $\alpha$ is a simple root in $R^+(\Delta)\setminus R^+ (\Delta')$, then $\beta(h_\alpha)=0$ for all $\beta$ in $R(\Delta')$???

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, the answer is clearly no.   Here the simple root `$\alpha$` is any simple root not in `$\Delta'$` and it need not be orthogonal to all roots in the subsystem.    

Comment: Can you give me an example where it fails?

Comment: Take `$\mathfrak{g} =\mathfrak{sl}_3$` with `$\Delta'$` containing just one simple root `$\beta$` and `$\alpha$` being the other simple root.

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/parabolic-subalgebra

Comment: There isn't necessarily any problem, but it's good to give links between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim gave me the answer!
It is false in general!

Thanks.